# show time in leaflet polyline onmouseover

Tags: javascript, leaflet

hi i create leaflet polyline with latlngs[]. in starndard wat we pass [lat,long] to latlngs[] but i want to pass third argument string dateTime and i wanna show in in span when point in polyline hovered by mouse.

sth like:

```
let latlangs = [ 
   [12.12, 12.12, '2020/12/12 - 10:30'], 
   [15.15, 15.15, '2020/10/10 - 12:30'] 
];

let antPolyline = new L.Polyline.AntPath(latlngs, options);

antPolyline.on('mouseover', e => {
        $('span').html('third argument string dateTime');
});
```

Comment: what does `new L.Polyline.AntPath(latlngs, options);` return because i know how to generally do what you mean but to get a specific part out of that is unknown as it is unknown to me :{

Comment: same as default leaflet polyline it returns polyline layer i think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the latlng where you mouse is over the polyline and then get the nearest point with informations:

```
var latlngs = [
  [19.04469, 72.9258, '2020/12/12 - 09:20'],
  [19.08469, 72.9058, '2020/12/13 - 10:30'],
  [20.13469, 72.9258, '2020/12/12 - 11:40']
]
var polyline = L.polyline(latlngs).addTo(map) //working same as ant polyline


polyline.on('mouseover',(e)=>{
  var point = findClosestPoint(e.latlng);
  var text = point[2];
  console.log(text)
  document.getElementById('testspan').innerHTML = text;
})



function findClosestPoint(latlng){
    var closestPoint = null;
  var distance = 0;
  latlngs.forEach((point)=>{
    if(closestPoint == null || distance > L.latLng([point[0],point[1]]).distanceTo(latlng)){
        distance = L.latLng([point[0],point[1]]).distanceTo(latlng);
      closestPoint = point;
    }
  });
  return closestPoint;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/falkedesign/Lbg3oqja/

Comment: i hope that i miss sth in documentation that other users don't, but i see there is no option to return single latlng[] to access third string.
your solution worked perfectly and thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You're asking to listen to the mouseover event of a certain HTML element to display some text.. Well does this help?

```
let lantlangs = [ 
  [12.12, 12.12, '2020/12/12 - 10:30'], 
  [15.15, 15.15, '2020/10/10 - 12:30'] 
];
let antPolyline = new L.Polyline.AntPath(latlngs, options);
//now to do what you asked
var mySpan=document.getElementById('mySpan')
mySpan.onmouseover=function(){mySpan.innerHTML=antPolyline[2]}
//the antPolyline[2] is my guess of what data you want displayed and I'm also assuming that the id of this specific span is 'mySpan'
```